# Extend a model to add methods

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, entity-framework

I have reverse engineered a MySQL database in a C# desktop app. What I would like to do is extend one of the model classes, so that I can add methods to it to use locally in my application. I don't want to change any properties  or anything just. Just get information and calculate things.

The problem is that when I inherit from one of the model classes I get an error about a new discriminator field being in the class but not the database.

Is there a way to do what I want to do?

Comment: Are those model classes partial, by any chance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given that the model classes are partial, you can just declare your own [partial classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wa80x488.aspx) to join them:

```
// Note - needs to be in the same namespace as the auto-generated declaration

public partial class Foo
{
    // Add your own methods here, which can refer to the properties declared
    // for the same type in the auto-generated code
}
```

The point of partial classes is that multiple files can contribute source to the same type.

Comment: That's the best way to extend your model classes (and the whole reason why they are declared as partial). As long as you extend them just by creating calculated methods and/or properties (or properties with the [NotMapped] attribute), everything will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

You could try [extension methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb383977.aspx) to accomplish this instead of inheriting and creating a new subtype.

You would "attach" the extension methods to the model class which you generated.

Comment: This looks very promising. I'll have to try it out tomorrow.
I'll report back if works out or not.